# Dell PowerConnect 5324 ignoring DHCPOFFER

Tags: dhcp, dell-powerconnect

I've recently procured a "new" Dell PowerConnect 5324. The firmware is updated to the current version and most of it works just fine. The exception is DHCP. When I enable DHCP, it cannot seem to request an IP successfully. "show ip interface" gives an IP address of 0.0.0.0/32.

It's worth noting that other devices on the same network, requesting from the same server, *through the misbehaving switch*, work just fine.

Connecting to that server and getting debug output from dhcpd shows me that the server is receiving a DHCPDISCOVER, sending a DHCPOFFER, and then . . . nothing. (Except for the occasional DHCPINFORM/DHCPACK pair from other devices on the network, again, communicating through the switch in question.)

Setting the switch to a static IP works fine - I can connect to its https web interface and maintain it from there, as well as ping other devices on the subnet. Adding the appropriate gateway allows it to ping exterior sites and even communication with sntp servers. I know the switch's OS is capable of receiving packets. It's just DHCP it seems to dislike.

I currently have no access control set, just for the sake of debugging.

Full config follows:

```
no spanning-tree
vlan database
vlan 66,100
exit
interface range ethernet g(2,4,6,8)
switchport access vlan 66
exit
interface range ethernet g(10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24)
switchport access vlan 100
exit
interface vlan 66
name 66
exit
interface vlan 100
name 100
exit
interface vlan 1
ip address dhcp
exit
username zorba password hunter2 level 15 encrypted
ip ssh server
ip https server
clock timezone -8
clock summer-time recurring 1 Sun Apr 02:00 last Sun Oct 02:00 zone PDT
sntp client enable vlan 1
clock source sntp
sntp client poll timer 14400
sntp unicast client enable
sntp unicast client poll
sntp anycast client enable
sntp broadcast client enable
sntp server 24.56.178.140 poll
sntp server 131.107.13.100 poll
sntp server 192.43.244.18 poll
```

I can't find any useful logging or packet monitoring on the switch itself. I'm officially out of ideas. What's next to troubleshoot this thing?

Comment: Dhcp helper in between ? They exist know bug if such. What version your dhcp server?

Comment: Is the DHCP server connected to a port in VLAN 1?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yep - in fact, the problem occurred before I had the VLANs set up, and *every* VLAN has a DHCP server.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I don't know what you mean by "dhcp helper" - it's connected directly to the dhcp server via wire, though, so there's nothing in between. I can't figure out how to determine the DHCP server version, but it's dhcpd, and it was the version packged with OpenBSD in 2010.

Comment: It's a cisco term for dhcp relay, but you answer me in your other comment, so ignore my comment, as it's not applying to you.